# How to delete the Cognito user in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, amazon-cognito

How to delete user account from * cognito * in nodejs.

I'm trying to delete the user from *cognito* it is not working for me.

**AWS config**

`const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();`

**Pool config**

`const poolConfig = {
    UserPoolId: keys.cognito.userPoolId,
    ClientId: keys.cognito.clientId
};`

Above configurations comes on top of below delete function.

*Delete Function*

```
function deleteUserFunc(req, decodedToken) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const decodedEmailid = decodedToken.email;
        const decodedSub = decodedToken.sub;
        try {
                const userDetails = { Username: decodedSub, Pool: userPool };
                console.log('DEBUG : ' + JSON.stringify(userDetails));
                const cognitoUser = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUser(userDetails);

                // Attempting to delete the user

                cognitoidentityserviceprovider.adminDeleteUser({
                    UserPoolId: keys.cognito.userPoolId,
                    Username: decodedEmailid
                    }, (err, data)=>                              
                        if(err) {
                        return reject({
                            error: err.message
                        });
                        } else {
                        return resolve({
                            error: null
                        });
                        }
                    }).promise().catch(err=>{
                    return reject({
                        error: err.message
                    });
                    });

                console.log('User deleteion status : ' + result);

                return resolve({
                    error: null,
                });
            });
        } catch (err) {
            return reject({
                error: err,
            });
        }
    });
}
```

I have also tried to delete the user with 
`const userDetails = { Username: decodedEmailId, Pool: userPool }` but no use.

Any help will much appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: 'access key id',
  secretAccessKey: 'secret access key',
  region: 'region',
});
const cognito = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();

await cognito.adminDeleteUser({
  UserPoolId: 'pool id',
  Username: 'username',
}).promise();
```

Note that the access token you're using within sdk should have `cognito-idp:AdminDeleteUser` permission on required pool.

Comment: It will work for you if you provide AWS credentials (region, access key, access key id) to `aws-sdk`. I can update my snippet to show you how.

Comment: I have updated my code according to your solution please check it out

Comment: @Rajath I also updated my code, have a look, I think it will give you a hint

Comment: For the newer syntax with the latest aws libraries checkout this article. They split up the libraries into separate installs and the syntax has changed. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-cognito-identity-provider/index.html

Answer (score 3):

The original answer by @Vladyslav Usenko helped me implement this newer version using the latest aws libraries.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-cognito-identity-provider/index.html

The documentation by AWS is very generic and difficult to figure out a solution, but here's an example that should help others.

```
const { 
    CognitoIdentityProviderClient,
    AdminDeleteUserCommand,
} = require("@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider");

const client = new CognitoIdentityProviderClient({ region: 'region-goes-here' });

var adminDeleteUserCommandInput = {
    UserPoolId: 'user-pool-here',
    Username: 'user-name-here' 
};
    
const adminDeleteUserCommandResults = await client.send(new AdminDeleteUserCommand(adminDeleteUserCommandInput));
console.log("adminDeleteUserCommandResults", adminDeleteUserCommandResults);
```